# Passing C# class between C++ functions

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am wondering if it is possible to pass my invoked C# object between c++ functions? I can already call my C# dlls from my native code, but now I need to pass a object between c++ functions which also means that I need to declare it in the header file...

When defining it in my header file I get the following error:

```
BOOL Exists(Api ^api);

Error   60  error C3395: 'ApiBase' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention
```

Does anyone know how I should handle this in my header?

Comment: Just stop using `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: Why? What to do instead?

Comment: `BOOL Exists(Api ^api);` is intended to be a part of native dll's api?

Comment: @johny Yes it is. The problem is that I cant remove the dll export because I am also wrapping the c++ code in my tests which is written in C#. Sorry if you missunderstand me somehow. I'm not a c++ master

Comment: You can export a C++/CLI function but it can never be one that uses a managed type as its argument.  Like Api^.  That doesn't make sense because exported functions are always used by unmanaged code, such code would never now how to pass a managed object.  Nor is it necessary at all, you can already use a `public ref class` from C#, just by adding a reference to the DLL.

Comment: Wait, by "pass between functions" do you mean a C++ function that completely ignores the object it receives, except calling in turn a C# function (possibly as callback) with said object as parameter? In that case, the `GCHandle` class is made specifically to handle such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You use `__declspec(dllexport)` to export a native C++ class. But it sounds like your class is a managed .net ref class. If you wish to export the functionality for both managed clients and unmanaged clients you need to declare two classes. One a managed ref class, and one a native class.

Or perhaps the issue is that you are trying to export a function that has managed parameters with `__declspec(dllexport)`. Again that is not possible.

Comment: Hmm ok. Maybe it's just easier and cleaner if I change this class that I need to pass between functions to a Singleton? That way I will have a global access point to it.